# how do i post dynamic inputs into another website

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post

my question is simple, how ican post all this inputs from website1 to website2

```
<form action="www.site2.com/charge.php" method="post"    name="charge">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_charge">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mywebsite email">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name'. $x .'" value="' .    $product_name . '">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_'. $x .'" value="' . $each_item['quantity '] . '">
<input type="hidden" name="weight_'. $x .'" value="' . $weightTotal . '">
<input type="image.gif" src="charge button image" name="submit" alt="Make charge!">
</form>
note: $X start from 1, and for each session $x= $i+1
```

thank you very much

Comment: use the action tag of the form

Comment: There is a problem: your php code must be between '<?php ... ?>'. Per example `name="item_name'. $x .'" value` has to be replaced by `name="item_name<?php echo $x ?>" value`

Comment: okay, but how www.site2.com/charge.php recive all data?

Comment: if the charge.php uses a POST request for its form, it's ok you code works. It the charge.php uses a GET request for its form, you should change method="post" by method="get"

Comment: okay, but the thing is difficult to me is, how do i wright the code on charge.php

Comment: which code ? the code of charge.php ?

Comment: yes, that's the code i want

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how do you acquire the data from your charge.php, you can do something like this:

```
$cmd = $_POST["cmd"];
```

and $cmd should now contain the data you typed into the form.

Old stuff:
*Provided your charge.php handles it, you can do like this:
Pass variables to the charge.php file using the URL:
www.site2.com/charge.php?cmd=dosomething&upload=somethingelse
In charge.php, handle the variables you've passed in:
You'd then use $_GET["cmd"] as the "cmd variable" you've passed in. and $_GET["upload"] as the "upload variable" you've passed in.
The downside to this is that the variables do appear in the URL bar, which could result in potentially confidential data being exposed.*

Comment: He uses HTTP POST request, not GET request.